# Is there a best way to make training data including entity?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson

Can Intent have wildcard replaced for entity within training data?
In case of intent trained by data including entity, confidence change depending on entity.
Is there a best way to make training data including entity?

Answer (score 1):

By default Watson Conversation automatically factors in entities into the training of intents.

Just be aware that the words themselves become keywords, when associating.

For example.

If you created an entity with value of `xxx` and your intent had **"What is xxx"**, then everything in the entity of `xxx` would be swapped out when created.

Now in your entity if you had `dog` as a value, it would only look for that keyword. It wouldn't understand that the word has a relationship with puppy for example, unless you explicitly put puppy into the entity.

There is more details [here](https://sodoherty.ai/2017/01/16/improving-your-intents-with-entities/). That was written before pattern entities.

Comment: Do Conversation replace value of entity in training data to entity? For example, Conversation's workspace have "@animal" entity which have "dog" as value and have "toy poodle" as synonym, and "#pet" intent which have "Do you have animal?" as training data. And then, I input this workspace "Do you have toy poodle?" .In case of this, Do Conversation replace "Do you have toy poodle?" with "Do you have animal?" ? I think that My input that includes synonym of "dog" in "@animal" is converted to "Do you have dog?",  and then converted to "Do you have animal?".

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use wildcards in intents because that’s not how NLP works. It needs access to the full sentence to process it.

What I see in most projects are examples with and without entities. For example, an intent to buy a house could use this:
- I want to buy a house
- I have to purchase a place
- I need to buy
- I am going to acquire 
- I have money for a 
- I need a home

Assume you have an entity house with some synonyms: place, apartment, home and etc.

So you have a intent for buying that is generalist but you have some examples with entities too.